# How to validate postcode in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, validation, oop

I'm trying to validate a postcode from a user input within a form. Using this class, i'm trying to  search through every character and check it. Then to call in within the form I have used the latter code. 
The problem i'm having is that an error pops up saying

"Conversion from string "True0" to type 'Double' is not valid."

```
Function VaidatePostCode(ByVal Post As String) As String


    For C = 0 To Len(Post) - 1



        If Char.IsLetter(Post(C)) & C = 0 Then
            _boolvalid = True
        Else
            _boolvalid = False
        End If


        If Char.IsLetter(Post(C)) & C = 1 Then
            _boolvalid = True
        Else
            _boolvalid = False
        End If



        If Char.IsNumber(Post(C)) & C = 2 Then
            _boolvalid = True

        Else


            _boolvalid = False
        End If



        If Char.IsWhiteSpace(Post(C)) & C = 3 Then
            _boolvalid = True



        Else


            _boolvalid = False

        End If


        If Char.IsNumber(Post(C)) & C = 4 Then
            _boolvalid = True

        Else


            _boolvalid = False
        End If


        If Char.IsLetter(Post(C)) & C = 5 Then
            _boolvalid = True

        Else
            _boolvalid = False

        End If


        If Char.IsLetter(Post(C)) & C = 6 Then
            _boolvalid = True

        Else
            _boolvalid = False

        End If

    Next C


    Return _boolvalid
End Function
```

This is the code within the VB.NET form

```
 Private Sub txtPost_Validated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtPost.Validated
    If myVal.VaidatePostCode(txtPost.Text) = False Then
        MsgBox("Please enter correct data format into postcode")
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried? This site is here to provide answers to specific problems, not to write your code for you.  From the error message you're trying to convert a string into a double when such a conversion isn't possible. You can't convert "True0" into a number. Try putting a break point at the top of your method and debugging it to see exactly where it is failing.

Comment: That code isnt going to do what you probably hope it will.  Since it is a loop and you dont exit upon finding an invalid character, `_boolvalid` keeps getting overwritten so it will only represent the state of the last character.  Also `&` is for string concatenation, not joining expressions, use `AndAlso`. Finally, turn on Option Strict for the error you are reporting here... a char is never ever going to be `1, 2, 3` etc - those are numbers

Answer (score 0):

To check if the value is a number you can use Integer.TryParse like this:

```
If Not Integer.TryParse(txtPost.Text, intTemp) Then
    MsgBox ...
```